# How to fix the time after restart the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i got a runner game and my player dies when it collides with an obstacle.I made a slow motion after the collision to make the game cooler. On the game over screen i got restart button and after i press it game starts again but the time is still slow. I couldn't solve the issue please help me. There is my slow-motion code

```
public float slowdownFactor = 0.05f;
public float slowdownLength = 4f;

private void Update()
{
    Time.timeScale += (1f / slowdownLength) * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
    Time.timeScale = Mathf.Clamp(Time.timeScale, 0f, 1f);
}


public void DoSlowMotion()
{
    Time.timeScale = slowdownFactor;
    Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * .02f;
}
```

This is my restart code

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level01");
}
```

I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Save the value pre-slowdown. Set it back during restart. Or even just have the default written in a configuration file. What exactly is the issue here? This is just 101 of data astorage.

Comment: You changed the value of timescale. It's still at what you set it at before.

Comment: I knew it was about timescale but i couldn't manage to solve it. It is my first time in coding c# and unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you never update the `Time.fixedDelatTime` as well. I would use a dedicated method in order to avoid redundant code like e.g.

```
public float slowdownFactor = 0.05f;
public float slowdownLength = 4f;

private void Update()
{
    SetTimeScale(Time.timeScale + (1f / slowdownLength) * Time.unscaledDeltaTime);
}

private void SetTimeScale(float scale)
{
    Time.timeScale = Mathf.Clamp(scale, 0f, 1f);;
    Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * .02f;
}

public void DoSlowMotion()
{
    SetTimeScale(slowdownFactor);
}
```

Then assuming a default `timeScale` of `1` you could simply do

```
private void Start()
{
    SetTimeScale(1f);
}
```

or in case your `Start` isn't called again (e.g. in case of using `DontDestroyOnLoad`) also do it before loading the scene

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    SetTimeScale(1f);

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Level01");
}
```